# Programmatically help user create a shortcut for watchKit app?

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, sirishortcuts

a newbie question.

I want to make it easy for users to create a shortcut to use Siri with a watchKit app. The app runs as a companion to an iOS version.

Where I've gotten so far: Users can successfully use Siri to make a voice request for each of the watchKit and iOS apps via intent extensions that I’ve created. That is, they can do so after a shortcut is available (e.g. “Hey Siri, jot myself”).

I would love to programmatically help users create both of these shortcuts. I’m stuck on the watchKit side, though.

The closest I’ve been able to get to make it easy for users to create shortcuts is:

- On the iOS app, as part of the app's onboarding, provide an “Add to Siri” button. (This works fine)
- Then, ask the user to go into Shortcuts in iOS, find the shortcut, look at its “Details” and toggle “Show on Apple Watch”. (This seems like it would be hard for users and I’m afraid asking them to do it will lose them.)

Is there a better way to help users set up the watchKit shortcut? Advice appreciated.